# OnClick Event Cancelled but PostBack Still Occurs in IE9 for Submit Behavior

Tags: asp.net, webforms

There is an `OnClick` event attached to a submit button on a webform. The button works in all browsers outside of IE9 correctly. The buttons validation is done by `parsleyjs`, which is where I would assume the problem is coming from; in that the `OnClick` event gets cancelled by the validation. However, the postback event still occurs. Even though the postback occurs, it does not fire the `OnClick` event.

A possible solution is switching to `UseSubmitBehavior="true"` which does work; however, I would rather figure out what is causing the postback to occur but not fire the event.

Comment: What do you mean by `after the postback the page does not contain the content that was set`? Which contents are you refering to? Can you expand or refactor your question for better understanding of your scenario?

Comment: Example is clarified, somewhat. But yes after the postback the mentioned div does not contained the set content as expected as its innerHTML.

Comment: Did you inspected the HTML received by the browser? Check if html is get by browser or not

Comment: Looking through it again, onclick event is not fired for the button; however, it does fire on all other browsers. Also a postback still does occur. :( Sorry

Comment: So this problem has nothing to do with `InnerHtml`. The problem is really about why the `Click` event didn't fire in IE9.

Comment: Just prepping an edit as soon as I can :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in the end, that `parsley.remote.js` an extension of `parsley.js` was somehow modifying the postback request, so that the `EVENTARGUMENT` was not supplied. Digging deeper into parsley.remote.js should give way to what is happening.

Removing the library (for me it was unused) corrected it.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of a div you could have an `asp:Panel` (which renders as a div); and change its `Visible` property at server side so this way you render it (or not) to the client.

Another option is to use `asp:Literal` which does not render a `div` and won't be sent back to the server in its ViewState.

Comment: Even if I could do that, I would like to avoid refactoring any place that InnerHtml is used on a server tag for IE9. Expected behavior is that the divs content should get set.